# BY-variable not shown in Univariate Frequencies?

Tags: sas

Is it usual that the Univariate Frequencies does not display the BY-variable while Univariate BasicMeasures does show the BY-variable?

In the example below I load in some data and want to show gas prices by zipcode. The output for `PROC FREQ` shows the BY-variable (`zipcode`) in the output as does the UNIVARIATE BasicMeasures. But the UNIVARIATE Frequencies is not showing the BY-variable in the output.

Am I doing something wrong? I've even set the templates to default, with the `ODS PATH` statement, in case the templates got messed up by other code (or other coders using same account).

```
DATA prices;
  INPUT  zipcode price;
  DATALINES;
90066 3.10
90066 3.17
90066 3.26
98101 2.99
98101 3.06
98101 3.16
;
run;
proc sort;
  by zipcode;
run;

ods path sashelp.tmplmst(read) ;

ods pdf file = "gasprices.pdf";
PROC FREQ data = prices;
  tables price;
  by zipcode;
run;    
ods select Frequencies;
PROC UNIVARIATE data = prices freq;
  var price;
  by zipcode;
run;
ods select BasicMeasures;
PROC UNIVARIATE data = prices;
  var price;
  by zipcode;
run;
ods pdf close;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify more than one object in the ODS SELECT, so you could pull both tables out of the same PROC FREQ like this:

```
ods pdf file = "gasprices.pdf"; 
ods select BasicMeasures Frequencies; 
PROC UNIVARIATE data = prices freq; 
  var price; 
  by zipcode; 
run; 
ods pdf close;
```

I know that doesn't exactly solve your problem, but it looks to me like the BY-variable display just isn't properly linked to the PROC UNIVARIATE frequency tables (e.g., try ODS SELECT Moments - works fine).  Might be worth reporting to SAS.

Comment: Cool, that's a good solution. Many thanks for the idea. Better than my inefficient alternate approach of splitting up data and manually filling in titles.